# Open a new window

Tags: javascript

How can i open a new window with this code? I wonder how i can open a new tab on a actual click event.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < GoData.length; i++)
  {
     var user = GoData[i];

     var row  = table.insertRow(-1);

     var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
     var link = usb.create('a');
     link.innerHTML = user['Incident'];
           link.href      = 'http://werk.intranet=' + user['Incident'];
     usb.on(link, 'click', (function(u) { return function() { usb.userRequest(u, true); }})(user['Incident']));
     cell.appendChild(link)

     cell = row.insertCell(-1);
     cell.innerHTML = user['Title'];
  }
```

Comment: [window.open()](https://www.google.com/#q=open+a+new+window+in+javascript)

Answer (score 0):

In your onClick function, you need to use `window.open(url)`.

Answer (score 0):

How to use window.open in my code?

usb.on(link, 'click', (function(u) { return function() { usb.userRequest(u, true); }})(user['Incident']));
     cell.appendChild(link)